# Uploading photos carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I'm trying to upload a series of photos using Carrierwave.

**Edit: Those are the updated files after fixing the array in Postman + Change in controller**

This is the controller:

```
class PhotoController < ApplicationController
  def upload_multiple
    photos_params.each do |uploaded_photo|
        @current_user.photos.create(:photo => uploaded_photo)
    end
    render json: {
      status: @current_user.photos.last.photo.inspect,
    }, status: 200
  end

  def photos_params
    params.permit(:photos => [])
  end
end
```

This is the photo.rb the model file for Photo:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

In user.rb I have

```
has_many :photos
```

And in the uploader the only uncommented lines are:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

In Postman, this is the how I upload the file:

[image]

Now records are being saved in the database, but no images are being uploaded at all. The directory uploads is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When just looping photo_params it is not working right, as the images are supposed to be looped in photo_params["photos"].

Try changing the code as :

```
def upload_multiple
  def upload_multiple
    photos_params["photos"].each do |uploaded_photo|
        @current_user.photos.create(:photo => uploaded_photo)
    end
    render json: {
      status: @current_user.photos.last.photo.inspect,
    }, status: 200
  end

  def photos_params
    params.permit(:photos => [])
  end
end
```

[image: Params in postman]

Comment: I changed url to be the name of the column in the database. Will edit the code now to reflect this change

Comment: Upvoted this for pointing out the url issue. Thanks for that. But the problem hasnt been solved yet though :/

Comment: Can you post the console log when the record is saved ?

Comment: I have just updated the question. Now there's the question and the result of inspect showing the image to be null. Would this be enough?

Comment: Hi, I figured out the answer. The photo_params is coming as an arrays of photos, when just looping photo_params it is not working right, as the images are looped in photo_params["photos"]. Have modified my answer, try it out.

Comment: At last!!
Thanks alot. Ive been on this for days. Cant believe its finally working